# Installing SharePoint February 2013 CUs

Tags: 2010, cumulative-update

I have 1 App and 2 WFEs. Is it okay to install the CU on all the server at the same time or they need to be install in a order. Once install is completed on all servers then I will run the PSConfig.

Please let me know if PSConfig needs to run in certain order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the CU on each server at the same time, but you will need to run the PSConfig one at a time.  Doesn't really matter on the order.

Microsoft has more detailed guidance on this at: [Install a software update (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806338(v=office.14))